# How to import animations into Blender?

Tags: animation, import, three.js, blender

I'm trying to import a js [file](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/marine/marine_anims.js)  with blending animations into Blender (v2.65) using the three.js (r66) importer, but it seems that the importer plug-in is not working properly, because nothing is shown in the scene. I tried to convert the js into an obj file and then import it into Blender, but only the mesh was imported, the blending animations were not imported. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the blender three.js json importer nor the obj file format support animations.